# Spark on Mesos: How to give an environment variable for driver and executor docker run

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

We are using spark framework in Mesos from universe and running drivers & executors as docker containers by setting the

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.mesos.executor.docker.image=mesosphere/spark:1.0.8-2.1.0-1-hadoop-2.6".
```

We are able to submit a job in cluster mode via

```
./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master mesos://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 12 --driver-memory 1G https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0.jar 20000
```

This successfully launched spark executors & tasks on multiple mesos nodes as docker containers.

In our mesos, we have container scoped roles inspired from lyft (https://github.com/lyft/metadataproxy).

Now I would like to run spark executors and tasks with their own container roles and essentially it requires us to set an environment variable IAM_ROLE=xxx for docker run command.
ex:

```
docker run -d -e IAM_ROLE=xxxx alpine:xxx
```

How can I launch a spark application using ./bin/spark-submit and give IAM_ROLE as an environment variable for all executors & tasks that start as docker run commands on mesos nodes.

Comment: `spark.executorEnv.SOME_NAME` can be used to set variables but I don't think it will help you if it has to be set when starting container.

Comment: Yes. I would like to set the environment variable for docker run